# Three.js change Matrix4 to Float64Array causes TypeError in Chrome/Opera. How to solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, three.js, opera

I'm using R62 of Three.js but I had some rounding errors which causes my objects to be at the wrong place in my scene. I'm not talking about a few pixels, the objects are plenty of pixels away from their expected position. I found out that `Matrix4` is the problem, `Float32Array` is not enough for my calculation. So I changed it to `Float64Array` and everything went fine.

I only tested in Firefox because that's the favorite browser for my target group. But now I had to test my application also in Chrome/IE/Opera to talk about the interoperability of it. I did it some months ago and all worked well, but now after my change in `Matrix4` nothing happened in Chrome/Opera and the console is full of `TypeErrors`.

Some long hours later, I found out that in `WebGLRenderer` in the function `setProgram` the following line causes the error:

```
_gl.uniformMatrix4fv( p_uniforms.projectionMatrix, false, camera.projectionMatrix.elements );
```

Chrome/Opera give `Uncaught TypeError: Type error` for `camera.projectionMatrix.elements` but why? Google told me, that this WebGL function expects a Float32Array and not Float64array, but why is there no error in Firefox? What can I do to get it work with Float64Array? Or is there another possiblility to avoid my big rounding errors?